# How to Get nextNode and PrevNode in List<IEnumerable>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here is my code

```
    public static class WorkFlowSteps
    {
        public static List<SaaSWorkflowMatrix> GetMatrixData()
        {
            List<SaaSWorkflowMatrix> matrixList = new List<SaaSWorkflowMatrix>()
            {
                new SaaSWorkflowMatrix()
                {
                     WorkFlowId="1",
                     UserName ="SubmitterUser"
                },
                new SaaSWorkflowMatrix()
                {
                     WorkFlowId="2",
                     UserName ="PeerUser"
                },
                new SaaSWorkflowMatrix()
                {
                     WorkFlowId="3",
                     UserName ="ManagerUser"
                },
                new SaaSWorkflowMatrix()
                {
                     WorkFlowId="4",
                     UserName ="ProcurementUser"
                },
                new SaaSWorkflowMatrix()
                {
                     WorkFlowId="5",
                     UserName ="SupplierUser"
                },
                new SaaSWorkflowMatrix()
                {
                     WorkFlowId="6",
                     UserName ="DataPrivacyUser"
                },
                new SaaSWorkflowMatrix()
                {
                     WorkFlowId="7",
                     UserName ="SecurityUser"
                },
            };
            return matrixList;
        }

        
    }

    public class SaaSWorkflowMatrix
    {
        public string? WorkFlowId;
        public string? UserName;


    }

    public static class WorkFlowStepsExtensions
    {
        public static SaaSWorkflowMatrix GetNextNode(this IList<SaaSWorkflowMatrix> coordinates, string username)
        {

            return coordinates.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.UserName==username);
           
        }

        public static SaaSWorkflowMatrix GetPrevNode(this IList<SaaSWorkflowMatrix> coordinates, string username)
        {

            return coordinates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == username);

        }




    }
```

The requirement is Passing the UserName must return the next user name and previous user name
i.e., If I pass SubmitterUserName the next user is PeerUser ,
If I pass PeerUser the nextuser should be ManagerUser and previous user should be submitteruser.

Right now I Have extension functions GetNextNode and GetPrevNNode, returning the same Node. Is it possible in List<> to get the previous nodes and next nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
public static class WorkFlowStepsExtensions
{
    public static SaaSWorkflowMatrix GetNextNode(this IList<SaaSWorkflowMatrix> coordinates, string username)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Count; i++)
        {
            if (coordinates[i].UserName == username)
                return coordinates[i + 1];  // Need error checking
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static SaaSWorkflowMatrix GetPrevNode(this IList<SaaSWorkflowMatrix> coordinates, string username)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Count; i++)
        {
            if (coordinates[i].UserName == username)
                return coordinates[i - 1];  // Need error checking
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is really inefficient though. Might be better to use a linked list or other data structure. Or track the current index so you can easily calculate the next and previous indexes.

Comment: is there a way to write it in one line using LINQ?

Comment: @Venkat: You would need to add a helper routine that returns the index of the match. Or you could add a comparer to your `SaaSWorkflowMatrix` class so that `List<T>.IndexOf()` can compare only the `UserName` property. Again, this is not a good approach. There are more efficient ways to organize this data.